# What power supply topology(ies) should I learn?

Tags: power-electronics

I am an electrical engineer with a few years of experience under their belt, and I have an interest in learning how to design power supplies for the consumer electronics and medical device industries.

So far I have learned the basic three - buck, boost, and flyback, but I want to expand my skillset into higher wattages (100 - 400 watts).

TI's power topologies handbook gave me a great list of topologies, but I am not sure which one(s) I should learn about next.

I found this chart on  https://www.smps.us/topologies.html

[image]

After looking into the 2-switch forward and active clamp forward converters, it looks like those are mostly used in automotive applications, based on the typical input voltage I saw in TI's reference design library (36V - 72V). Is the next best thing the LLC half bridge and the Half bridge?

TL;DR What is a good topology for a 100W - 400W power supply that takes universal AC input (85VAC - 265VAC)?

Comment: It depends on your application and what tradeoffs you're willing to make. Do you prefer maximum efficiency or minimum cost? How much ripple can you tolerate on the output? Does it need to be able to start a motor?

Comment: Basically, if there was one single best topology, there wouldn't even *be* multiple topologies to pick from, because everyone would just use that one.

Comment: You can have a look at the free SIMPLIS [simulation templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) I posted which cover many different topologies starting from the basic switching cells to multiphase and resonant converters. Most of them work with the free demo version. Simulation is a great tool to learn and understand operation details. Bench experiments are then the next step to consolidate your knowledge.

Comment: In reality, PS choice is make/buy.  If you want to buy, you must learn what specs are important tradeoffs and how regulation errors and noise with stability margin tests are done to qualify the best choices and how to validate assumptions with measurement techniques like 50 Ohm AC coupled spectral density, step overshoot, surge power on startup ratio to load power ! and EMI issues.  To learn design requires you to master this and then learn much more details.  So I suggest you learn by reverse engineering designs with full schematics and compare a variety of products.

Comment: So learn theory to match tests in practice to understand strength/weaknesses, efficiency/fault sensitivity. But in practice, design is much different. It's about learning how to make great detailed specs, expanded to detailed design where DCR,ESR,Ron and loop compensation methods affect damping and overshoot to disturbances and ripple greatly.  But start simple then work your way up to 1 GW power if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You may not get a satisfying answer on this. I would just recommend you read on power electronics if you are interested in designing SMPS’s. Maybe start with a book that covers the fundamentals before looking at individual topologies (e.g. Robert Erickson’s book). After that, reading about different topologies will be much more impactful.

There’s tradeoffs between topologies, and you will be a great designer when you have awareness of them and can create a SMPS that hits each requirement for your application. Unless you’re comfortable with the analysis, you may end up with your solutions boxed in or derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I would start from the simplest and most used topology in AC/DC converters below 70 W: Flyback

Get your self the following lab tools:

1. Electronic load
2. Battery powered scope (*)
3. UL60950 norm (****)
4. A reference board to study (**)
5. TEX-E wire, enameled copper wire from 0.3 to 1 mm diameter, some RM10 ferrite cores, a rasp, feeler gauge  (***).
6. Temperature logger (Yokogawa is the most used) and probes

(*) It's very important probing signals with a battery powered scope because ordinary scopes have the black crocodile clip connected to Earth. That means that you will short your board at the very first measure. It happened to me the very first day I had to study a competitor's board.

(**) I started from NXP's UM10758 because NXP always certifies their boards by bringing them to an anechoic chamber for EMI signature. It's a 60 W AC/DC power supply for notebooks.

(***) The most important part in a flyback power supply is the transformer. You can say "I can design AC/DC converters once you know how to design and manually make a transformer that is UL6090 compliant".

(****) That norm is important for clearance distances inside the transformer and on the PCB. You will have to know what UL means by insulation systems and what yellow cards are.

The airgap of the transformer is the most important thing in a flyback converter.

All energy per cycle is stored in the airgap, that is, in the air and not in the ferrite core.

It's important the overall volume of the airgap and not the linear distance in the air.

We like small airgaps with big area ferrite cores. That allows us to have big volumes with small airgaps.

RM10 cores are the best.

---

One last thing: people call it transformers but in the flyback context they work as coupled inductors. This is why:

During Ton, energy is stored in the airgap by the MOSFET.

During Toff, energy is delivered from the airgap to the load.